# How to add a time delay in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am building a chat room in `JFrame`.
I want the `JFrame` to refresh each **200ms** so that whenever a new text is entered, it will appear inside the `JFrame`.

I tried using `while(true)` but `JFrame` freezes.

How to add timer to the code?

Comment: `while(true)` is not a good idea, your'e tying up the EDT, that's why it get stuck.

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: why not just refresh when new message is arrived instead of repeated refreshing?

Comment: _How to add timer to the code?_ By using a `javax.swing.Timer`

Comment: How to make it refresh when message arrives?
in the example there are multiple jframes, each consists of users online, chat area and message area.

Comment: You can use observer pattern..search about that or  read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623897/using-oo-observer-pattern-without-updating-object-from-which-change-originated

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

Comment: awful lot of people seem to be writing JFrame chatrooms lately. Is this a homework?

Answer (score 3):

> I am building a chat room in JFrame. I want the JFrame to refresh each
>   200ms so that whenever a new text is entered, it will appear inside
>   the JFrame.
>
> I tried using while(true) but JFrame freezes.
>
> How to add timer to the code?

- disagree, `JFrame` can't be refreshed only `JComponent` (`JTextComponent`) and only in the case that on second side are some changes
- `200milisecond` is very short time, you can't wrote text message on this short period, I'd be to set `750milis - one second`
- use `util.Timer` or to start endless loop from `Runnable#Thread`,
- use boolean local variable instead of `while(true)`, e.g  `while(canRun)`, then is possible the loop to stop and start if would be need
- all output to the `Swing GUI` from `util.Timer` / `Runnable#Thread` must be wrapped into `invokeLater`, only methods with real changes, methods from `Swing APIs` e.g. `setText()`, `append()` not whole method, void which is responsible to create an output, connection, etc.
- don't to use `SwingWorker`, isn't proper API for endless loop, is designated to runs only once time,
- then there is possible concurency with a few instances of `SwingWorkers`(invoked from any `Timer` or `Executor`), because nobody can to guarantee that every ended and aren't (a few instances) live in the same time, then best of choices is loop invoked from `Runnable#Thread`

Comment: new point for me, so jdk 7? :) by the way thread in link doesn't seems to be a question... I wonder why was it not closed :))

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to timer class as well

```
Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//Some code here

}
});
timer.start();
```

for more details see [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Hope this will help you.